# javascript - handling 'UnknownError'

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, indexeddb

I'm writing error handling code for my web application.
Currently I'm testing saving blob to object store when there is no sufficient privileges for reading from the file:

```
transaction.objectStore("files").put(object, key);
```

After this line of code is executed I'm getting `UnknownError` but I don't know how to handle it. I tried wrapping this line in try/catch block but catch part is never executed. Any hints?

Comment: only FF can store blob

Comment: And how does this relate to my question?

Comment: Storing blob object to IndexedDB is not widely supported. Currently only Firefox support the feature.

Comment: still - how does this realte to my question? The question is - how to handle 'UnknownError' not how to support storing blob to IndexedDB on all browsers.

Comment: Show the surrounding code, not just the one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all errors just attach to the `window.onerror` event.

```
window.onerror = function(){
    //your code
    return false;
}
```

If you want to catch that specific IndexedDB error, attach on the IndexedDB request onerror event:

```
request.onerror = function(){
    //your code
    return false;
}
```